# Excel VBA OnAction Event doesn't work, but doesn't error either

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I have the following code that dynamically creates buttons:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i, sInfo As String


    For i = 2 To GetLastRow("Deliverables", "A")

    sInfo = "CmdButton" & i

    Me.Buttons(sInfo).Delete


    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(Cells(i, "AA").Left + Cells(i, "AA").Width * 0.05, Cells(i, "AA").Top + Cells(i, "AA").Height * 0.05, Cells(i, "AA").Width * 0.9, Cells(i, "AA").Height * 0.9).Select
    With Selection
        .Caption = "Update Task: " & Cells(i, "B").Value
        .Name = sInfo
        .Text = "Update Task: " & Cells(i, "B").Value
        Selection.OnAction = "CmdButton2_Click"

    End With
    Next
End Sub
```

This runs without errors but what I can't seem to get working is the Selection.OnAction event.  When I click the button nothing happens.  I am trying to get the OnAction event to call another Sub I have in my VBA code.  I've tried a few examples from here and other places on the web, can't seem to get them to work.

Anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: Where's the `CmdButton2_Click` sub? If not in a regular module then you need to prefix it with the object module name - e.g.  `Sheet1.CmdButton2_Click`

Comment: What is in `CmdButton2_Click`? Ensure it is not blank. Your code works for me just fine.

Comment: @TimWilliams: If the onaction cannot find the `CmdButton2_Click`, it will give an error. Like Op mentioned he is not getting any errors...

Comment: @SiddharthRout - I read that as possibly meaning "this runs without errors *except for* Selection.OnAction"

Comment: This code works fine for me. As Sid mentions, make sure the `CmdButton2_Click` contains executable code.

Comment: CommandButton2_Click is just a message box statement to tell me if I am getting there or not.  I think I had to restart excel because now I see an error when I click the button:  Cannot run the macro 'Deliverables!CmdButton2_Click'.  The macro may not be available in this workbook or macros may be disabled.

The macro should be in the workbook.  If I place the cursor in the CmdButton2_Click sub and press F5, I see the message box as it should be.  

I changed the OnAction code to be:  Selection.OnAction = "Deliverables!CmdButton2_Click"

Still gives me the same message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works for me

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i, sInfo As String, c As Range
Dim rngUpdate As Range, rw As Range, r As Long
Dim tsk As String

    Set rngUpdate = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C2:G20"))

    If rngUpdate Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Set rngUpdate = rngUpdate.EntireRow

    For Each rw In rngUpdate.Rows

        r = rw(1).Row
        sInfo = "CmdButton" & r

        On Error Resume Next
        Me.Buttons(sInfo).Delete
        On Error GoTo 0

        Set c = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, "B")
        With ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(c.Left + c.Width * 0.05, _
                                c.Top + c.Height * 0.05, _
                                c.Width * 0.9, c.Height * 0.9)

            .Caption = "Update Task: " & Cells(r, "C").Value
            .Name = sInfo
            tsk = Cells(r, "C").Value
            .Text = "Update Task: " & tsk
            .OnAction = "'Sheet1.CmdButton2_Click """ & tsk & """'"

        End With
    Next rw

End Sub

Sub CmdButton2_Click(r)
    Debug.Print "clicked update for : " & r
End Sub
```

Comment: What I needed to do was add my sheet name like you have to the OnAction event.  I had tried "Sheet!CmdClick" but that wasn't working, but "Sheet.CmdClick" did.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a button and have it call a Macro Routine with the below code:

```
Sub CreateButton()
Dim I, sInfo As String
Dim sBut
    I = 2        
    sInfo = "CmdButton" & I

    ActiveSheet.Buttons(sInfo).Delete

    Set sBut = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlButtonControl, _
        Cells(I, "AA").Left + Cells(I, "AA").Width * 0.05, Cells(I, "AA").Top + Cells(I, "AA").Height * 0.05, Cells(I, "AA").Width * 0.9, Cells(I, "AA").Height * 0.9)
    With sBut
        .Name = sInfo
        .OnAction = "MyMacro"
        .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Update Task: " & Cells(I, "B").Value
    End With
End Sub

Sub MyMacro()
MsgBox "You Clicked Me"
End Sub
```